# Create a vector given N input of names and ages python

Tags: python, dictionary, vector

I need to create a program that takes as inputs multiple entries of names and ages. Then I want it to return the names and ages of those entries that have higher age values than the average age of all entries.
For example:

```
input( "Enter a name: ") Albert   
input( "Enter an age: ") 16

input( "Enter a name: ") Robert   
input( "Enter an age: ") 18

input( "Enter a name: ") Rose  
input( "Enter an age: ") 20

The average is = 18
Rose at 20 is higher than the average.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answers = {} 
# Use a flag to indicate that the questionnaire is active. 
questions_active = True 
while questions_active: 
# Ask for the person's name and response.
    name = raw_input("\nEnter a name: ") 
    response = raw_input("Enter an age: ")
# Store the response in the dictionary: 
    answers[name] = int(response)
# Check if anyone else is going to take the questionnaire. 
    repeat = raw_input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/ no) ") 
    if repeat == 'no': 
        questions_active = False

average_age = sum(answers.values())/float(len(answers))
print("The average is " + str(average_age))
# Questionnaire is complete. Show the results. 
for name, response in answers.items():
    if response > average_age:
        print(name.title() + " at " + str(response) + " is higher than the average.")
```

This answer is based on a similar example from the book "Python Crash Course: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming" https://www.nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse